# JSF not invoking jQuery function properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf

I have the following code in the bean:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("setFocus();");
```

(I debugged it and I'm 100% sure it is running).

And then in XHTML:

```
function setFocus() {
     $('#codItem').focus(); 
     console.log($('#codItem'));
 }
```

The console.log is printing the HTML element properly, what I don't get is why .focus() is doing nothing at all.

I tried even with a setTimeout() in order to be sure it is not losing focus because any other event over there.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is component type that has id="codItem"? Can you provide example from your JSF page?